# How to select from table where condition (and) is for some rows

Tags: oracle

I'm using oracle 11.

I have some table

```
+---------+-----------+--------+--------+
| attr_id | record_id | value1 | value2 |
+---------+-----------+--------+--------+
|       1 |         1 | 2      | null   |
|       2 |         1 | null   | 6      |
|       3 |         1 | 4      | null   |
|       1 |         2 | null   | 4      |
+---------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

And I want to select like this:

```
select record_id from table
where ((attr_id = 1 and value1 = 2) and (attr_id = 3 and value1 = 4))
```

I expect output record_id = 1.

How can I do it?

Comment: if you want, you can do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it well, you want to select the `record_id` having *both*:

- `(attr_id = 1 and value1 = 2)` is one row and
- `(attr_id = 3 and value1 = 4)` in an other row.

You can't use a simple `SELECT` in table `WHERE` clause here, as it will check for the condition in the *same row*, which can't be satisfied (`attr_id` can't be equal to `1` and `3` in the same row). So [your query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73a490/1) can't work.

*But*, there is one solution. You will need a [self-`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Self-join), producing all combinations of pairs of (attr_id,value) for a given `record_id`.

As I suppose you are relatively new to SQL, I will build my answer in several steps:

### self-join

As I said before, we need first to join your table with itself:

```
select t1.attr_id as attr_id_1,
       t1.value1 as value1_1,
       t2.attr_id as attr_id_2,
       t2.value1 as value1_2,
       record_id
from t as t1
join t as t2 using(record_id)
```

producing:

```
ATTR_ID_1   VALUE1_1    ATTR_ID_2   VALUE1_2    RECORD_ID
1           2           1           2           1
2           (null)      1           2           1
3           4           1           2           1
1           2           2           (null)      1
2           (null)      2           (null)      1
3           4           2           (null)      1
1           2           3           4           1       <---------
2           (null)      3           4           1
3           4           3           4           1
1           (null)      1           (null)      2
```

(live example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73a490/6)

As you can see, all combinations of rows having the same `record_id` are in that result set. Including combinations of a row with itself. Please notice I have spotted the row that you are looking for.

### Get the "right" record

Now, it is quite easy to get the `record_id` having both `(attr_id = 1 and value1 = 2)` `(attr_id = 3 and value1 = 4)`. You only have to take care of prefixing your column with the correct table alias:

```
select t1.attr_id as attr_id_1,
       t1.value1 as value1_1,
       t2.attr_id as attr_id_2,
       t2.value1 as value1_2,
       record_id
from t as t1
join t as t2 using(record_id)
where t1.attr_id = 1 and t1.value1 = 2
  and t2.attr_id = 3 and t2.value1 = 4
```

Producing:

```
ATTR_ID_1   VALUE1_1    ATTR_ID_2   VALUE1_2    RECORD_ID
1           2           3           4           1
```

(see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73a490/8)

### The final answer

Finally, it is quite easy to polish a little bit the query to return only the desired value:

```
select record_id
from t as t1
join t as t2 using(record_id)
where t1.attr_id = 1 and t1.value1 = 2
  and t2.attr_id = 3 and t2.value1 = 4
```

Comment: Thank you, it's the best way